# gunicorn workers timeout on some apps only

Tags: python, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm setting up dev/prod environments for an nginx/supersvisord/gunicorn/flask app comprised of 10 microservices. Each environment runs on 1 GCE instance.
Everything works fine on the prod environment, and on 7 apps of the dev environment.
But 3 other apps aren't starting: curl on (local) address just waits (but doesn't say that connection is refused), and workers are timeouted and booted again every 2 minutes (according to `gunicorn -t` parameter).
Also, when I terminate these apps with `supervisord stop`, the processes take maybe a minute to shut down (functional apps' processes shutdown immediately).
How can this be fixed?

Application code, supervisord config and owner rights for files and folders are  same for both environments.

I'm using Python 3.5, gunicorn 19.6.0, supervisord 3.3.1.

Here's a sample supervisord config of an app (configs for all apps are same):

```
[program:platform]
command = <virtualenv_dir>/bin/gunicorn main:app -w 4 -b 127.0.0.1:8000 -t 120 --log-level=DEBUG
directory = <app_dir>
user = <username>
```

Here's debug from supervisord log (again, the gunicorn config output is same for all apps, working or not):

```
    [2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32197] [DEBUG] Current configuration:
  ciphers: TLSv1
  errorlog: -
  preload_app: False
  max_requests_jitter: 0
  daemon: False
  limit_request_field_size: 8190
  keepalive: 2
  django_settings: None
  enable_stdio_inheritance: False
  statsd_host: None
  paste: None
  logconfig: None
  pre_request: <function PreRequest.pre_request at 0x7f1b398149d8>
  accesslog: None
  proxy_protocol: False
  logger_class: gunicorn.glogging.Logger
  on_reload: <function OnReload.on_reload at 0x7f1b39809c80>
  post_fork: <function Postfork.post_fork at 0x7f1b398141e0>
  worker_int: <function WorkerInt.worker_int at 0x7f1b39814510>
  threads: 1
  proxy_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  syslog: False
  syslog_prefix: None
  pre_exec: <function PreExec.pre_exec at 0x7f1b39814840>
  spew: False
  forwarded_allow_ips: ['127.0.0.1']
  default_proc_name: main:app
  worker_abort: <function WorkerAbort.worker_abort at 0x7f1b398146a8>
  reload: False
  cert_reqs: 0
  workers: 4
  tmp_upload_dir: None
  backlog: 2048
  proc_name: None
  worker_exit: <function WorkerExit.worker_exit at 0x7f1b39814c80>
  limit_request_line: 4094
  sendfile: None
  loglevel: DEBUG
  capture_output: False
  group: 1004
  ca_certs: None
  statsd_prefix: 
  when_ready: <function WhenReady.when_ready at 0x7f1b39809e18>
  umask: 0
  secure_scheme_headers: {'X-FORWARDED-SSL': 'on', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTOCOL': 'ssl', 'X-FORWARDED-PROTO': 'https'}
  syslog_facility: user
  bind: ['127.0.0.1:8000']
  chdir: /var/www/rokit/platform
  worker_tmp_dir: None
  pythonpath: None
  limit_request_fields: 100
  suppress_ragged_eofs: True
  worker_connections: 1000
  max_requests: 0
  config: None
  do_handshake_on_connect: False
  pidfile: None
  on_starting: <function OnStarting.on_starting at 0x7f1b39809ae8>
  pre_fork: <function Prefork.pre_fork at 0x7f1b39814048>
  access_log_format: %(h)s %(l)s %(u)s %(t)s "%(r)s" %(s)s %(b)s "%(f)s" "%(a)s"
  syslog_addr: udp://localhost:514
  on_exit: <function OnExit.on_exit at 0x7f1b39819048>
  worker_class: sync
  keyfile: None
  raw_env: []
  post_worker_init: <function PostWorkerInit.post_worker_init at 0x7f1b39814378>
  check_config: False
  certfile: None
  ssl_version: 3
  graceful_timeout: 30
  post_request: <function PostRequest.post_request at 0x7f1b39814ae8>
  user: 1004
  timeout: 120
  nworkers_changed: <function NumWorkersChanged.nworkers_changed at 0x7f1b39814e18>
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32197] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.6.0
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32197] [DEBUG] Arbiter booted
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32197] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:8000 (32197)
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32197] [INFO] Using worker: sync
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32200] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32200
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32202] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32202
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32203] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32203
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32204] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32204
[2016-08-18 12:57:39 +0000] [32197] [DEBUG] 4 workers
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32197] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:32200)
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32200] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 32200)
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32197] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:32202)
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32202] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 32202)
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32197] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:32203)
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32203] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 32203)
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32197] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:32204)
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32204] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 32204)
[2016-08-18 12:59:39 +0000] [32289] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32289
[2016-08-18 12:59:40 +0000] [32197] [DEBUG] 1 workers
[2016-08-18 12:59:40 +0000] [32290] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32290
[2016-08-18 12:59:40 +0000] [32292] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32292
[2016-08-18 12:59:40 +0000] [32293] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 32293
[2016-08-18 12:59:40 +0000] [32197] [DEBUG] 4 workers
[2016-08-18 13:01:40 +0000] [32197] [CRITICAL] WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:32289)
```

Comment: after deleting the VM and making another VM from scratch, nothing changed.
If I bind gunicorn to other IPs (e.g. 127.0.0.1:800x instead of 127.0.0.x:8000), same apps refuse to run.

Comment: Starting gunicorn without supervisor doesn't change anything.